# Why and When there is need to re-declare static method in derived class if its definition cannot overridden/altered by derived class?

Tags: java, static

I am familiar with `static` keyword, and how it used. I understand that a `static` method can be re-declared in sub-class but its definition gets hidden and remains same as of parent class. I am mentioning some links of articles I've already read:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/can-we-overload-or-override-static-methods-in-java/

[Why doesn't Java allow overriding of static methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223386/why-doesnt-java-allow-overriding-of-static-methods#comment2357434_2223386)

[Difference between Static and final?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772827/difference-between-static-and-final)

When a derived class defines a static method with same signature as a static method in base class, the method in the derived class hides the method in the base class. But still the method of base class is called such as `display()` method  of base class.

But I am curious as to why and when there is a need to re-declare `static`
method of `base class` in derived class if its definition cannot
overridden/altered in the derived class and the definition of base class is displayed instead?

```
    /* Java program to show that if static method is redefined by 
a derived class, then it is not overriding. */

// Superclass 
class Base { 

    // Static method in base class which will be hidden in subclass 
    public static void display() { 
        System.out.println("Static or class method from Base"); 
    } 

    // Non-static method which will be overridden in derived class 
    public void print() { 
        System.out.println("Non-static or Instance method from Base"); 
    } 
} 

// Subclass 
class Derived extends Base { 

    // This method hides display() in Base 
    public static void display() { 
        System.out.println("Static or class method from Derived"); 
    } 

    // This method overrides print() in Base 
    public void print() { 
        System.out.println("Non-static or Instance method from Derived"); 
} 
} 

// Driver class 
public class Test { 
    public static void main(String args[ ]) { 
    Base obj1 = new Derived(); 

    // As per overriding rules this should call to class Derive's static 
    // overridden method. Since static method can not be overridden, it 
    // calls Base's display() 
    obj1.display(); 

    // Here overriding works and Derive's print() is called 
    obj1.print();    
    } 
}
```

Comment: Helpful article about the static keyword: https://www.baeldung.com/java-static

Comment: There is never a _need_ to, only an option to, which may lead to user confusion if you take that option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main take-away here is: Don't use *instance* variables to call `static` functions. Java allows it, but it's confusing because it looks like an instance method call when it isn't.

This line creates a `Derived` instance, and assigns it to a `Base`-typed variable:

```
Base obj1 = new Derived();
```

Later, when you type:

```
obj1.display();
```

what really happens is:

```
Base.display();
```

because `obj` is a variable of type `Base` and `display` is a `static` method. In fact, if you look at the compiled bytecode, you see that it's *literally* that call, the instance variable isn't mentioned anywhere:

```
public class Test {
  public Test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: new           #2                  // class Derived
       3: dup
       4: invokespecial #3                  // Method Derived."":()V
       7: astore_1
       8: aload_1
       9: pop
      10: invokestatic  #4                  // Method Base.display:()V
      13: aload_1
      14: invokevirtual #5                  // Method Base.print:()V
      17: return
}
```

Notice the difference between the `obj1.display()` call

```
      10: invokestatic  #4                  // Method Base.display:()V
```

and the `obj1.print()` call:

```
      13: aload_1
      14: invokevirtual #5                  // Method Base.print:()V
```

The `static` call **doesn't** push `obj1` on the stack, and uses `invokestatic`. The instance call **does** push `obj1` on the stack (`aload_1`), and calls `invokevirtual`.

If you declared `obj1` of type `Derived`, you'd see the opposite behavior. With:

```
Derived obj1 = new Derived();
```

then

```
obj1.display();
```

outputs:

```
Static or class method from Derived
```

because it's really:

```
Derived.display();
```

It's all about the *type* of the instance variable. The type of the instance itself doesn't matter at all (in fact, `obj1` could be `null`).

Don't call `static` methods via instance variables. Instead, use the class name.

> I understand that a `static` method can be re-declared in sub-class but its definition gets hidden and remains same as of parent class.
>
> ...
>
> When a derived class defines a `static` method with same signature as a static method in base class, the method in the derived class hides the method in the base class.

Those two statements contradict each other. The relationship is this: The derived `static` method overrides the base `static` method when referenced via the derived class. So with your code, `Base.display` references `Base.display` and `Derived.display` references `Derived.display`. The fact there's a `display` on `Derived` doesn't affect the one on `Base`, which is still accessible via `Base` (or a `Base`-typed variable). (If you didn't have `display` in `Derived`, `Derived.display` would reference `Base.display`,  but since you do, it doesn't.)

> But I am curious as to why and when there is a need to re-declare static method of base class in derived class...

The only time you need that is if you want `Derived.display` (or `obj1.display` when `obj1` is declared as `Derived`) to do something different from `Base.display` (or `obj1.display` when `obj1` is declared as `Base`). One example I can think of is methods that create instances, perhaps via the Builder pattern:

```
Base b = Base.builder()
         .setName("the name")
         .setAnswer(42)
         .setBiz("baz")
         .build();
```

vs.

```
Derived d = Derived.builder()
         .setName("the name")
         .setAnswer(42)
         .setBiz("baz")
         .setDerivedThingy("whatever")
         .build();
```

Comment: okay. Please make correction if I am mistaken in understanding the main concept. As per my understanding, I've reached to the conclusion that in case of `static method` same copy is shared between all instances of a class and that's why `Base obj1` is ignoring  `new Derived()`  and calling `Base.Display()` instead `Derived.display()`

Comment: @Emmy - The instances aren't involved **at all**. This works: `Base obj1 = null; obj1.display();` It's true there's only one copy of `Base.display` and one copy of `Derived.display`, but that's true of the instance method `print` as well. What's important is that since it's a `static` method, the instance isn't used. The compiler sees `obj1.display()` and does `Base.display()` because the type of `obj1` is `Base`. That's a compile-time thing. (And one of the great mistakes in the Java language. It makes no sense to allow `static` calls through instance refernces, and only confuses people.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for an instance while invoking static member or method.

Since static members belongs to class rather than instance.

[Example 15.11.1-2. Receiver Variable Is Irrelevant For static Field Access](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#d5e19846)

The following program will make your doubt clear.It demonstrates that a null reference can also be used to access a class (static) variable without causing any Null pointer exception:

```
class Test {
    static String name = "Jaspreet";
    static Test method1(){
        System.out.print("Hello world");
        return null;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(method1().name);
    }
}
```

And the analysis of why it is happening

> Even though the result of method1() is null, a NullPointerException
>   is not thrown. That "Hello world" is printed demonstrates that the Primary
>   expression is indeed fully evaluated at run time, despite the fact
>   that only its type, not its value, is used to determine which field to
>   access (because the field name is static).